# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDate' , NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

Hi I'm trying to get a date from NSUSerDefault and when i try to cast AnyObject to NSDate i get this error :

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x101d6bef0) to 'NSDate'
```

here is the full code :

```
if let some = brain.defaults.objectForKey("Today")  {

        let demoo = NSDate().secondsFrom(some as! NSDate)
        brain.numberCount = Float(demoo)
        brain.defaults.synchronize()
        brain.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startButtonUIButton.hidden = true
        brain.progressCircle.strokeEnd = CGFloat(demoo/86400)

    }
```

the erro is on this line :

```
let demoo = NSDate().secondsFrom(some as! NSDate)
```

any idea why?

Comment: `some` is a `NSString`, not a `NSDate`. You can't convert that easily a `NSString` to a `NSDate`. Either you have to use a `NSDateFormatter`, or if it's a time stamp, you could translate it as a `NSTimerInterval` and then into a `NSDate`.

Comment: @Larme actually some in AnyObject. i checked it a few times. I'm looking for a way to convert AnyObject to NSDate or save NSDate directly to NSUserDefault.

Comment: `some` is a `NSString` stored as `AnyObject` for `some as! String` will work and `some as? NSDate` will return nil.  You should check that when you set the default for "Today" you are setting the right value or if you truly want a string in the defaults, use an `NSDateFormatter`.